# Line plus bar chart in ggplot2

Tags: r

I am trying to plot line plus bar chart using ggplot but I am getting the error "Error: ggplot2 doesn't know how to deal with data of class uneval"

```
require(ggplot2)    
df.1 <- data.frame(x = c(1:5), y = rnorm(5))
df.2 <- data.frame(x = c(1:10), y = runif(10))

p <- ggplot(df.1, aes(x=x, y=y)) + 
    geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
    geom_line(df.2, aes(x=x, y=y))
```

x-axis scale for both data frames is always same but one needs to be plotted as line chart while the other needs to be plotted as bar chart. It seems to me that two data frames are not supported in ggplot2. Is there a work around to overcome this?

I tried using nvd3 through rCharts but is doesn't seem to support linePlusBarChart as of now.

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just explicitly override the `data=` parameter:

```
ggplot(df.1, aes(x=x, y=y)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  geom_line(data=df.2, aes(x=x, y=y))
```

note, it's actually because data's the 2nd attribute by default for plot layers (different from the base ggplot call), so `geom_line(aes(x=x, y=y),df.2)` would also work

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. This works perfect. By the way, is there a way to add tooltips for ggplot2?

Comment: @Troy, thank you so much for your example.  I had similar plotting problem and was stuck because I could not find any tutorials or examples online to build a combo bar and line chart with just few lines of code.